# PHP help needed for Login script

Tags: php, forms, authentication

When I login with the correct username and password I get an error "Wrong Username or Password" the database connection works and I think there is something wrong with the password + username check.

```
    <?php
    $host="mysql12-int.cp.hostnet.nl"; // Host name
    $username="u33936_mick"; // username
    $password="//password was correct"; // password
    $db_name="db33936_axe"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name


    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name");



    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 0, 30 WHERE username="$myusername" and        
    password="$mypassword"';
    $result=mysql_query($sql);


    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);



    if($count==1){
      session_register("username");
      session_register("password");
      header("location:index.php");
    } else {
      echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ?>
```

This is my form

```
     <form name="login" method="post" action="login.php">
                <fieldset id="inputs">
                    <input id="myusername" type="text" name="myusername"    
    placeholder="Username" required="">  
                    <input id="mypassword" type="password" name="mypassword"      
    placeholder="Password" required="">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="login.php">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </style>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: man is not looking for advice he is looking for solution.

Comment: `echo $count;` -maybe for some weird reason it's more than 1 ? maybe it's zero ?

Comment: @SenadMeškin this advice will be way more helpful (in the long run) than the solution.

Comment: doesn't the `limit` clause need to go at the end of the query?

Comment: get some ideas here (#1 php login script on github): https://github.com/panique/php-login/blob/master/1-minimal/classes/Login.php

Comment: @SenadMeškin Use of the **deprecated** `mysql_` functions is a critical problem in any code. No solution is complete or even ethical when it does not entail advise on discarding deprecated techniques. The widespread use of `mysql_` is dangerous to the language and to internet security in general, and is actually a bigger problem than whatever minor and temporary problem he is asking about here. He'll figure out the string concatenation with the answers he has, but if he doesn't figure out PDO he's got bigger problems.

Comment: @Panique your constructor does too much, and reads super globals? Ewwww :p

Comment: @Chris I totally agree! But that's only the minimal, reduced and simple as possible version. Btw those are constants. I think it totally right for this case. In general, it's bad architecture, yes, but i posted this file to get the questions an idea how to handle the SQL/session part...

Comment: @Chris then I can also say, don't use PHP or MySQL that is critical problem, PHP is script language that doesn't have variable types, and MySQL is not good as MSSQL or Oracle, so please don't use them. Use ASP.NET MVC C# for web development and LINQ to SQL for Database Access to SQL server.
Do you see the point now?

Comment: Reductio ad absurdum, we should just not use computers at all! You can say "don't use PHP or MySQL", but that is strictly a matter of opinion -- we aren't here to blog about our personal preferences. It is a fact that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and that fact is very important and relevant. Your or my personal opinions on language or DB superiority are not important or relevant, generally speaking, and definitely not helping the OP with his code. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foremost, I suggest you look in to transitioning away from the deprecated `mysql_*` family of functions in favor of `mysqli` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) or PDO ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)), neither of which require any significant change on your part as far as code goes.

As for your specific bug, it appears that you are incorrectly concatenating the values into the query. Also, your `WHERE` and `LIMIT` order is incorrect and invalid SQL. Here is the correct form:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        `users` 
    WHERE 
        username="'.$myusername.'" AND 
        password="'.$mypassword.'"
    LIMIT 0, 30 
';
```

It is not clear what advantage you bring by using the `LIMIT` statement. Either you should have one matching row, or none. If anything, I would use `LIMIT 1`. If you got 30 rows back, what would you do with them!?

Converting to PDO is easy! The same query in PDO would look like this:

```
$host="mysql12-int.cp.hostnet.nl"; // Host name
$username="u33936_mick"; // username
$password="//password was correct"; // password
$db_name="db33936_axe"; // Database name

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            `users` 
        WHERE 
            username=:username AND 
            password=:password
        LIMIT 0, 30 
');
$sth->execute(array('username'=>$myusername, 'password'=>$mypassword));
$user = $sth->fetch();
```

Note that when you use PDO with bound parameters (shown here), you DO NOT have to sanitize with `mysql_real_escape_string` or `addSlashes` as you have done in your code.

It is not clear where you are defining `$mypassword` and `$myusername`, but if you are using registered globals then you should alter your code. Get the values directly from `$_POST`. `addSlashes` is NOT safe, and neither are registered globals.

**Documentation**

- Deprecation notice for `mysql_*`  functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- PHP String operators - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
- PHP PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- PHP `mysqli` - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: thank you! but now my homepage displays that u33936_mick is logged in instead of the account i logged in with

Comment: I think you're mixing up your database username & password with `$_POST['myusername']` and `$_POST['mypassword']`. That is why using registered globals is a bad idea :) I don't know what's in your database, or what you do after the database check, but make sure you don't use `$username` anywhere, because that's the DB username, not the logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

- You should use `$_POST['myusername']` etc. to get the posted variables. If you are relying on [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) you should turn that off as it is deprecated and poses a security risk;
- The `LIMIT` clause comes at the end in mysql;
- You should not modify the sent-in information using functions like `stripslashes` and escape functions, instead you should use prepared statements with bound variables in PDO / mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and passwords can contain for example slashes.

As a side-note, you should really salt and hash your password, don't store plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: Good note about registered globals! I added that to my answer as well, to be certain future readers get the hint. +1